# Error response with Sabre SOAP API - StructureFareRulesRQ

Tags: sabre

When trying to perform a StructureFareRulesRQ using Sabre SOAP API i keep getting the below response. Is this because the airline doesn't support structured fare rules or something else? thank you

```
    <StructureFareRulesRS xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2003/07" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Version="1.0.4">
        <Errors>
            <Error ErrorCode="005106" ErrorMessage="FORMAT FARE BASIS NOT AVAILABLE"/>
        </Errors>
    </StructureFareRulesRS>
```

Comment: could you share your request with us?

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly related to the way the service is built. Remember that fare components o not necessarily reflect segments, and check the directionality of the fare. If you are using BFM, the service will return fare directionality and the actual cities you have to use. Sometimes fares are loaded as full in ATPCO, not only by segments, so that means that the city pair you will have to use in your request will be what you can see in FareComponentBeginAirport and FareComponentEndAirport in BFM's response. I would advise to check with the helpdesk, as you can send them your full payloads and they can check in your PCC as well.